# Extracting nested items from a JSON object without loop using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a nested JSON object, and I want to extract 2 items ('id' and 'name') from the nested item.
I can do this with a loop, but my approach feels very clunky- even as a newbie.
Can someone suggest a more elegant approach?

```
groups_requests ={'@odata.context': 'http://wabi-australia-southeast-redirect.analysis.windows.net/v1.0/myorg/$metadata#groups', '@odata.count': 2, 'value': [{'id': '53d06b2423-690f-4923-8f65-db710c038566', 'isReadOnly': False, 'isOnDedicatedCapacity': False, 'name': 'Steves_Test_App_workSpace'}, {'id': '988f6d4ea-14b2-4ad7-a899-ae4v0d974c9139', 'isReadOnly': False, 'isOnDedicatedCapacity': False, 'name': 'DataflowsTest'}]}

import pandas as pd
p=(groups_requests['value'])
mlis = []
for i in p:
    lis =[]
    lis.append(i['id'])
    lis.append(i['name'])
    mlis.append(lis)
df = pd.DataFrame(mlis)
df.columns = ['Workspaceid', 'Workspacename']
df
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to get rid of loop:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [(e['id'], e['name']) for e in groups_requests['value']],
    columns=('Workspaceid', 'Workspacename')
)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Will invest time in learning comprehensions!